# avoiding patterns using python

Tags: python, combinatorics

For the sequence {6,2,3,1,5,4}, we have the corresponding diagram on the right. For every 3 increasing numbers in the sequence: {2,3,5} , {2,3,4}.
We check if it follows the pattern on the left. This is a combinatorics object called boxed-mesh patterns. My code currently checks if the sequence has 3 increasing numbers

[image]

Comment: You're gonna need to explain more what you're trying to do here.

Comment: For the sequence of numbers {2,3,4} you realize there is the point 1 within the end of the shaded area, which goes against the pattern. I will like my program to see this. I used a list of lists to organize the numbers as like the frame on the left. I dont know if that will even help. This idea follows a boxed mesh pattern in combinatorics

Comment: @SamuelMensah pleas explain about your shape!  seems that black points are the numbers can you show that any point is what number?

Comment: The points represents the numbers in the sequence, in the example in the shape on the right. The program must note the point:1, because it violates the pattern

Answer (score 3):

You can use of following list comprehension to grub the expected sequences :

```
>>> [(e1,e2,e3) for i,e1 in enumerate(l) for j,e2 in enumerate(l[i+1:],1) for e3 in l[j+i+1:]]
[(6, 2, 3), (6, 2, 1), (6, 2, 5), (6, 2, 4), (6, 3, 1), (6, 3, 5), (6, 3, 4), (6, 1, 5), (6, 1, 4), (6, 5, 4), (2, 3, 1), (2, 3, 5), (2, 3, 4), (2, 1, 5), (2, 1, 4), (2, 5, 4), (3, 1, 5), (3, 1, 4), (3, 5, 4), (1, 5, 4)]
```

Then you can filter the result of preceding list comprehension with following function that check the alternating of your elements :

```
>>> def seq_check(elem):
...   return elem[2]>elem[1]>elem[0]

>>> filter(seq_check,sequences)
[(2, 3, 5), (2, 3, 4)]
```

Comment: I have written the code to this point. Thanks, this will also be efficient. I will like to check if {2,3,5} and {2,3,4} follows the pattern on the left. Both do not, because the pattern do not have points in the shaded area> How does my program recognize these points

Comment: @SamuelMensah First seems that we have a person here that is love with downvote!!! :P second if you find this answer helpful you can vote and accept! third can you explain about your picture more pleaaaas!

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Hi grate downvoter @PadraicCunningham , as the OP says *this will also be efficient* :) and also i have got an up vote!

Comment: that is irrelevant, the question is not how can I make my code more efficient, the OP has a specific question that you have not remotely addressed. Your code does exactly what the OP's is already doing. The only way someone upvoted is if they did not read the question properly

Comment: @PadraicCunningham If you explain 100000 lines still there is no reason to down vote! you just can leave a comment !